# Error android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I am following the Android by Udacity course, but by pressing the refresh button to retrieve the json that error appears in my logcat, what could be happening, putting this permission in manifest.xml not resolved ....I'm using Galaxy S3 device.

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as         > user -2 but is calling from user 0;this requires >android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   int id = item.getItemId();
   if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
     FetchWeatherTask tempoTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
     tempoTask.execute("87047100");
     return true;
   }
   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding this in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"/>
```

hope it helps